# Password digest can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, bcrypt

Ruby on Rails 3.2

My form is creating a new distributor. I have added the `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'`, my database table has `password_digest: string` and my model has `:password, :password_confirmation,` and `has_secure_password`.

When I submit my form the error I get is `Password digest can't be blank`.

This is what is POSTed:

```
Started POST "/distributors" for x.x.x.x at 2014-03-14 12:59:07 -0700
Processing by DistributorsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x=", "distributor"=>{"company_name"=>"First Account", "company_website
"=>"First.com", "contact_name"=>"First", "contact_email"=>"first@moon.com", "contact_title"=>"owner", "company_phone"=>"555-665-5555", "company_region"=>"Asia Paci
fic", "company_address"=>"172 E Center Street", "company_country"=>"Cambodia", "company_city"=>"Covina", "company_state"=>"Not Applicable", "company_zip"=>"01970",
"sales_contact_name"=>"Bob", "sales_contact_email"=>"bobby@moon.com", "tech_contact_name"=>"Steph", "tech_contact_email"=>"steph@moon.com", "additional_name"=>"",
"additional_email"=>"", "additional_name2"=>"", "additional_email2"=>"", "area_served"=>["", "Bangladesh"], "terms_and_conditions"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
Distributor Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `distributors`.* FROM `distributors` WHERE `distributors`.`contact_email` = 'first@moon.com' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
Distributor Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `distributors` WHERE `distributors`.`contact_email` = 'first@moon.com' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Does someone know what I'm missing? Thank you

Comment: can you show us your model?

Comment: `Password digest` value is not getting set. Did you add any `attr_accessor` for password and password_confirmation in your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log is missing both the password and password_confirmation fields being set. It should look more like this

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dsdfhjdskhfsdfhjsdfhjsdfhjdsfhjsdfE=", "user"=>{"email"=>"email@provider.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
```

Comment: I thought that bcrypt was supposed to add a password. Will it filter the passwords automatically? Any links to examples or tutorials?

Comment: I just grabbed the logs of an app where I do password filtering. This railscast shows how password filtering can be done: http://railscasts.com/episodes/9-filtering-sensitive-logs?view=comments. Chapter 7 of the rails tutorial shows how to setup a form for user signup: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#top. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The hash you post to your `distributors` route does not contain any information about a password. It is not possible to create a distributor without a password, with the code you have written. So the error message is perfectly correct.

You need to add a `password` and a `password_confirmation` field to your webpage.

Comment: Is there a way to have it make a temporary password?